# How do I get CXF to generate external XSD for the WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, cxf

I'm using CXF with the `@WebService` annotation.  It generates the WSDL file as one big file, is there a way I can tell it to generate the `wsdl:types` externally in an XSD file and import them into the WSDL?

Answer (score 1):

1) Your best option is use CXF's `JavaToWS`, just provide your implementation class and domain objects with `"-createxsdimports"` option, it will create separate WSDL and XSD files for you,

see below example **from my website**

http://www.javatips.net/blog/2012/09/cxf-java2wsdl-example

2) You can use SOPERA suite http://www.sopera.de/en/downloads/sopera-asf-331 and it converts into separate WSDL and XSD