# Separate XSD schema from WSDL file for CXF servlet

Tags: cxf, java-ws

Is it possible to setup CXF servlet to generate XSD schema separated from WSDL file?

I have properly configured CXF with WS available at `http://localhost:8080/wstest/ws/` and at `http://localhost:8080/wstest/ws/MyWs?wsdl` is WSDL file available.

I just want to modify the configuration to have xs:schema in separate file and to have import in WSDL file.

Comment: Possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094826/how-do-i-get-cxf-to-generate-external-xsd-for-the-wsdl